# Dynamicaly write text in textbox while performing action

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have simple WPF form in .NET, which allows mw to select directory and then perform some action on files in them

I have button, which triggers the action (it is transforming XML files to csv). This takes some time, so I would like to write into textbox information about the number of files processed etc.

I can do that, but all messages which are send to textbox during `Click` action are shown after the whole procedure is finished. What I want, is to send messages to textbox while processing the data in `Click` method.

This is method triggered on click:

```
 private void processButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      List<string> allXmlFiles = ProcessDirectory(selectedDir);
      textbox.Text += String.Format("\n{0} files will be processed", allXmlFiles.Count);
      if (allXmlFiles.Count > 0)
      {
           textbox.Text += "\nProcessing files...";
           foreach (string filepath in allXmlFiles)
           {
                try
                {
                     ParseFile(filepath);
                }
                catch
                {
                     textbox.Text += String.Format("\nCannot process file {0}", filepath);
                }
           }
      }

      textbox.Text += "\nDone";
 }
```

How can I make the messages ("X files will be processed", "Processing files...", "Cannot process file XYZ") appear while calculating and not after?

Comment: It looks like there's a way to control when a TextBox is updated. I can't test this so I won't provide it as an answer, but try it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754356.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this because you are starting your parsing synchronously to overcome your issue try  BackgroundWorker  with something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        BackgroundWorker bckg =  new BackgroundWorker();
        private List<string> allXmlFiles;   
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bckg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bckg_DoWork);
            bckg.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bckg_ProgressChanged);
            bckg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bckg_RunWorkerCompleted);


        }

        void bckg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error!=null)
            {
                textbox.Text += String.Format("\nCannot process file {0}", filepath);
            }
        }

        void bckg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //here you can update your textblox 

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    textbox.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
                });

        }

        void bckg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            allXmlFiles = ProcessDirectory(selectedDir);
            if (allXmlFiles.Count > 0)
            {

                bckg.ReportProgress("here in percentage", "\nProcessing files...");
                foreach (string filepath in allXmlFiles)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ParseFile(filepath);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;  
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            textbox.Text += String.Format("\n{0} files will be processed", allXmlFiles.Count);
            bckg.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!
Works just fine. I am still having some trouhle displaying the progress, but the problem is solved.

Comment: In case of to have BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged worked, BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress should be set to true

Answer (score 0):

This is happening, because your operations are synchronous. Extract your processing files operation in another thread. If you are using `.NET 4.5+`, try adding the async word in the method:

```
private async void processButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your 'Click' event call another method which handles this logic to end this method as soon as possible.

Otherwise a simple work around to what you already have would be to have a method to update your log information.

For example:

```
UpdateText(String newText)
{
    textBox.Text += "\r\n" + newText;
}
```

With this, using your loop, you could report the number of files processed. You could do this in chunks to avoid spam.

Your for loop, with suggestions:

```
int numProcessed = 0;
foreach (string filepath in allXmlFiles)
{
    try
    {
        ParseFile(filepath);
        numProcessed++; // or you could use '++numProcessed' inline

        if(numProcessed % 10 == 0 && numProcessed >= 10)
            UpdatedText("Another 10 files processed!");
    }
    catch
    {
        UpdateText(String.Format("\nCannot process file {0}", filepath));
    }
}
UpdatedText("Finished");
```